# Run batch file which run another cmd file

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, ssh, cmd

I have script in batch file:

```
cd C:\TESTS\front-tests
call git pull
cd C:\TEST\front-tests\AutoApp\bin\debug
start AutoApp.exe
```

And I want to call git pull but it fails. Permission denied. 
But after I write from hand command to run "start-ssh-agent.cmd" and after that i call git pull it works.

My question is how to modify the batch file which will do git pull and after that run AutoApp.exe?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a little snippet here for easily running batch files as admin. See if this helps.

```
::You'll need this because my snippet uses delayedexpansion heavily.
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

::Restore running directory. Put this before any file operations. I usually put it near the top.
if !CD!==%SystemRoot%\system32 pushd %~dp0

::Put this after where you exit the script.
:admincheck
net session > nul 2>&1
if not %errorlevel%==0 goto continuecheck
if exist "%temp%\uacprompt*.vbs" (
    del "%temp%\uacprompt*.vbs" > nul 2>&1
    exit /b
)
:continuecheck
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 > nul
net session > nul 2>&1
if not %errorlevel%==0 goto nouac
exit /b

:nouac
call :printui Administrative privileges not found. Requesting...
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 > nul

echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\uacprompt%instance%.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\uacprompt%instance%.vbs"
"%temp%\uacprompt%instance%.vbs" > nul 2>&1

::Check if uacprompt.vbs script exists. VBS script should be deleted when Admin prompt launches.
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
if exist "%temp%\uacprompt%instance%.vbs" (
del "%temp%\uacprompt%instance%.vbs" > nul 2> nul
echo This script requires Admin privileges to run^^! Exiting...
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 >nul
exit
)
exit
```

Comment: Can you modify my script? I tried a few combination of this code but it's failed.